# Laravel relationship query where using array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to return all the attributes from my database that have a set foreign key (Attribute groups). I've set up all the relationships in my model but I'm unsure how to query these relationships using a collection or array.

AttributeGroup -

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Attribute', 'group_id');
}
```

Attribute -

```
public function attributeGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AttributeGroup');
}
```

My current query -

```
$page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

$groups = AttributeGroup::where('page_id', $page->id)->get()->toArray();

$atts = Attribute::where('group_id', $groups[0]['id'])->get();
```

This works because we have set the specific index of the array using `$groups[0]`

Is there a simple way I can pass an array through to the query using their relationships or is looping through the results and then passing my own array to the query the best approach?

```
$attributes = array();
foreach ($groups as $group){
   array_push($attributes, $group['id']);
}
$atts = Attribute::where('group_id', $attributes)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$groups` is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections). [Assume them as arrays on steroids](https://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/arrays-on-steroids). Therefore you can use the [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) method to get those ids you need:

```
$page = Page::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
$groups = AttributeGroup::where('page_id', $page->id)->get();
$atts = Attribute::where('group_id', $groups->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Also if you've set your relationships correctly, you should be able to loop through `$groups` and access the attributes of those `$groups`. You can test it:

```
$groups = AttributeGroup::where('page_id', $page->id)->get();
dd($groups->first()->attributes);
```

Comment: Ah that's brilliant I knew there would be a better approach thank you. If I used pluck and wanted to add something to that collection e.g the ```group_name``` would I need to go back to building up my own array?

e.g using the query above the ```$groups``` collection has a ```group_name``` value inside, and I wanted to return and associate that with the ```$atts``` in the view

Comment: You can pass multiple columns to `pluck()` and then use `map()` to modify the collection as you need it to.

Comment: Ah so I'll be able to use map to add the ```$groups->name``` to each ```$atts``` result?

Comment: Every time you call `->get()` you get a collection and all the methods are available to you.